# iPhone distribution provisioning problem

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I'm trying to distribute my iPhone application and doing everything like in apple's manuals. And finally, there is no embedded.mobileprovision in MyApp.app. And also there is nothing about it in Built results. I followed all the recommendations (like clean all targets, clear CodeSign identity, remove all build directories and launch xCode again) and still have no progress.

What am i doing wrong?

There is one more thing i'd like to ask about. In Distribution configuration I've added Entitlements.plist, but builder shows me a warning:
CodeSign warning: entitlements are not applicable for product type 'Application' in SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.1.2'; ignoring...
May be these two things are connected with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For distribution on the AppStore, you need not to have an Entitlements file.

Comment: ok, i've suspected that. i just was a little confused by apple's recommendations in their "how to" manual.

Comment: what about first part of ny question? i've tried dozens of adviced found in web and got no effect.

Comment: actually, i have one suggestion: before i've registered in iphone developer program and got certficates, i've been experementing with self-signing (fake certificates). may be some remains of that activity do affect on my problem? sorry for my English.